# Entity Framework - running queries on a cloned/cached DBset

Tags: c#, entity-framework, caching, iqueryable

I am using a context object that inherits from `System.Data.Entity.DbContext`:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MyObjectConfiguration());
    }

    public DbSet<MyObjectClass> MyObject{ get; set; }
}
```

This is my code to use the `dbset`:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    IQueryable<MyObjectClass> myQueryable = context.MyObject();
}
```

I want to run queries on `myQueryable`, but I do not want it to run on the DB itself - I want it to run on a locally cached one (which will be refreshed every XXX time).

What is the best way to achieve that?

Comment: Are you trying to Mock data? Not clear what you want to accomplish. 
Does this help you? -> https://www.thecodebuzz.com/dbcontext-mock-and-unit-test-entity-framework-net-core/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping it simple you can make a small adjustment to how you are using your context.

```
public void Main () 
{
    // Cached collection...
    IQueryable<ItemClass> items;
    
    using ( context = _factory.CreateContext () ) 
    {
        items = context.Set<ItemClass> ()
            // Don't track the items returned by this query.
            .AsNoTracking()
            
            // Select all items.
            .Select ( e => true )
            
            // This will create a HashSet and populate it with the query results.
            .ToHashSet ()
            
            // Cast HashSet to IQueryable 
            .AsQueryable ();
    } // context gets disposed but we can still query the HashSet we created.
    
    // items is still in scope query it without making additional database queries.     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `context.MyObject.Local`, but it's IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your objectives and the amount of data in question you might also consider synchronizing data to something like an in-memory database periodically so that your application can run general queries against the in-memory copy. (fast) Provided the data is tracking a last modified timestamp, a background process can run to keep changes in-sync between the two data sources.

From there I would back this up with consolidation checks across the cached data copies to report on any data that might be left out of sync and have a process to record delta anomalies and force refresh the entire cache.

Comment: what are the benefits of using an in-memory db over just holding a cached IQueryable collection (which will be updated periodically)?